# What is the appropriate way to clear eventlisteners from fabricjs canvas?

Tags: fabricjs

I am using fabricjs. When I want to clear the canvas I use [canvas.clear()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#clear) method.

However, I have attached event listeners (such as *'object:over'*) to the canvas, so I need to clear those out also. The docs do not clarify whether .clear() takes care of that.

Comment: No, `clear()` does not touch listeners. You'd need to remove them manually (save references when assigning them, then pass to `.off()`)